# Vercel serverless nodejs + CORS issue

Tags: node.js, cors, vercel

I have been googling for solution since two day before still didn't get the solution that why I am asking here

API (nodejs) and reactjs both hosted in vercel - how to solve this CORS issue

**This is the error message**

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxx-backend.vercel.app/api/xxx' from origin 'https://xxxxx-vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*

I set in app.js

**app.use(cors());**